# Заполнение поля Input с помощью кнопок в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Много где искал информацию, но именно моего вопроса так и не смог найти :( Я реализую веб - калькулятор на Django. У меня будет поле input,в которое пользователь может ввести самостоятельно какой либо текст, а также кнопки со значениями (0..9, + - * / и тд.). Подскажите, как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в поле input добавлялся символ, привязанный к этой кнопке?

**Пример:**

Поле input: **Пусто**

Пользователь нажимает кнопку **8**

Поле input: **8**

Пользователь нажимает кнопку **/**

Поле input: **8/**

Искал проекты - калькуляторы на Django,В одном из проектов была реализация, но она реализована с помощью скриптов на JavaScript, к сожалению, я его не понимаю и не знаю, если я скопирую этот код, будет ли он работать :( Подскажите с идеями для реализации, буду вам глубокопризнателен